# Alternative for enum - when seeding a database

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am right now in the design phase of a new app and am doing some research. I came across the CodeFirst approach of EF 4.3 and really liked it.

However there is one design goal, I am not sure how to achieve.

Let say I have a task class:

```
    public class TaskModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TaskType Task { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TaskType
    {
        Sales = 0,
        Marketing = 1,
        CustomerService = 2
    }
```

I know that enums are currently not supported in EF 4.3. Hence this code would not even generate a proper database model. However I don't even need enums. Since what if the user would like to add a new TaskType at runtime?

Hence I think its best to have the TaskType as a class, which would become a table in itself and the user could add more entries. But how do I make them map together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case it is common one-to-many relation:

```
public class TaskModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual TaskType Task { get; set; }
}

public class TaskType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TaskModel> TaskModels { get; set; }
}
```